# Speed up the mullite operator cross product and dot product in numpy python

Tags: performance, numpy, cross-product

I have a loop in one part of my code. I tried  to change all vectors into an example to make it simple as see in below sample. I have to try it this loop 230000 inside the other loop. this part take about 26.36.
is there any way to speed up or tune the speed to get optimized speed.

```
trr=time.time()
    for i in range (230000):
         print(+1 *0.0001 * 1 * 1000 * (
         1 * np.dot(np.subtract([2,1], [4,3]), [1,2]) + 1
         * np.dot(
             np.cross(np.array([0, 0, 0.5]),
                      np.array([1,2,3])),
             np.array([1,0,0]))
         - 1 * np.dot((np.cross(
             np.array([0,0,-0.5]),
             np.array([2,4,1]))), np.array(
             [0,1,0])))    )
    print(time.time()-trr)
```

the  code with variable:

```
 For i in range (23000):
        .......
        .....
    
    
         else:
                                            
            delta_fs = +1 * dt * 1 * ks_smoot * A_2d * (
             np.dot(np.subtract(grains[p].v, grains[w].v), vti) * sign +
              np.dot(np.cross(np.array([0, 0, grains[p].rotational_speed]),
              np.array(np.array(xj_c) - np.array(xj_p))),
               np.array([vti[0], vti[1], 0])) * sign
               - np.dot((np.cross( np.array([0, 0, grains[w].rotational_speed]),
                np.array(np.array(xj_c) - np.array(xj_w)))), np.array(
                [vti[0], vti[1], 0])) * sign)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `i` loop?  Just timing?  I don't see `i` used in the calculation.  The calculation just uses constants, so it can be run once.  There's nothing to improve, that I can see.

Comment: I just make it simple. The code has a loop in which must update some arrays and vectors. all vectors must be updated 23000 times with these operators. my question is  what is the fastest way rather than numpy.

Answer (score 1):

It would've been better if you kept your examples in variables, since your code is very difficult to read. Ignoring the fact that the loop in your example just computes the same constant value over and over again, I am working under the assumption that you need to run a specific set of numpy operations many times on various numpy arrays/vectors. You may find it useful to spend some time looking into the documentation for [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). Here's a very basic example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

CONST = 1*0.0001*1*1000
a0 = np.array([2.,1.])
a1 = np.array([4.,3.])
a2 = np.array([1.,2.])
b0 = np.array([0., 0., 0.5])
b1 = np.array([1.,2.,3.])
b2 = np.array([1.,0.,0.])
c0 = np.array([0.,0.,-0.5])
c1 = np.array([2.,4.,1.])
c2 = np.array([0.,1.,0.])

@nb.jit()
def op1(iters):
    for i in range(iters):
        op = CONST * (1 * np.dot(a0-a1,a2)
                      + 1 * np.dot(np.cross(b0,b1),b2)
                      - 1 * np.dot(np.cross(c0,c1),c2))
op1(1) # Initial compilation

def op2(iters):
    for i in range(iters):
        op = CONST * (1 * np.dot(a0-a1,a2)
                      + 1 * np.dot(np.cross(b0,b1),b2)
                      - 1 * np.dot(np.cross(c0,c1),c2))

%timeit -n 100 op1(100)
# 54 µs ± 2.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 op2(100)
# 15.5 ms ± 313 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Seems like it'll be multiple order of magnitudes faster, which should easily bring your time down to a fraction of a second.

Comment: You have one issue in your Numba code that can cause a hard to find error. Global variables (variables that are not explicitly passed to the function) are getting hardcoded into the function. If you change one array the result wont change. Apart from that you can explicitly write out all dots and cross products (`(b0[1]*b1[2]-b0[2]*b1[1])*b2[0]+...`). This will give an additional speedup of about a factor of 200, because you avoid costly function calls.

Comment: Thanks. So, in order to use the Global variable like as a matrix and also use the Numba method as explained above, how can I  make a function. The loop body has many parts, so how I can define Numba  just has control for some parts of the inside loop body?

Comment: @HoomanDEM Pass all numpy arrays explicitly. It looks like you are using some objects like `grains[w].rotational_speed`. It would be a lot easier if you only use plain numpy arrays.

Comment: @max9111. thanks. explicitly writing is worked much faster than numpy. I supposed numpy is much faster but for this case is not. thank you

Comment: @HoomanDEM It is not really a numpy or numba issue. You could try the same in Fortran or C. BLAS algorithms are much faster for larger arrays. But on really tiny operations  it is usually better to inline it (at least in compiled code).